# Error in Flutter : RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an E-commerce app in flutter [Dart].

I am trying to get data from firebase where I have collection name (Vendor Collection). In this collection I have documents and some fields in that documents but when I try to access those data it return Range error.

```
This is my code where I got error: 
FutureBuilder(
    future: StoreServices.getProfile(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(child: loadingIndicator(circleColor: white));
      } else {
        //controller.snapshotData = snapshot.data!.docs[0];
        var data = snapshot.data!.docs[0];
        return Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              leading: Image.asset(imgProduct)
                  .box
                  .roundedFull
                  .clip(Clip.antiAlias)
                  .make(),
              title: boldText(text: "${data['vendor_name']}"),
              subtitle: normalText(text: "demo@gmail.com"),
            ),
            const Divider(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: List.generate(
                    profileButtonIcons.length,
                    (index) => ListTile(
                          onTap: () {
                            switch (index) {
                              case 0:
                                Get.to(() => const ShopSettings());
                                break;
                              case 1:
                                Get.to(() => const MessagesScreen());
                                break;
                              default:
                            }
                          },
                          leading: Icon(
                            profileButtonIcons[index],
                            color: white,
                          ),
                          title:
                              normalText(text: profileButtonTitles[index]),
                        )),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    },
  ),
```

This is my file where I created method:

```
class StoreServices {
 static getProfile() {
  return firestore
    .collection(vendorCollection)
    .where('id', isEqualTo: currentUser!.uid)
    .get();
  }
}
```

This is my Firebase :

[image]

I try to print vendor name and vendor details which has in documents but I got an error. I want to access those data from firebase

Comment: Seems like function getProfile is not working as your expectation. It is returning empty data, so when you try to access first element you get range error. Please double check your getProfile method (collection and filter).

Comment: Check whether the vendorCollection variable is correctly set to "vendors" and also check the user id

Comment: @RashmiRekha I checked all this and it is set correctly.

Comment: It seems to be that there is no document in the vendors collection for `.where('id', isEqualTo: currentUser!.uid)`. If this is an expected use-case for your app, your code will need to handle the case where it gets a snapshot without documents back from `getProfile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DocumentSnapshot` to fetch one single document if you know the document ID:

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getProfile() async {
  try {
    final profile =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("name").doc('uid').get();

    if (!profile.exists) {
      throw Exception("Profile not found");
    }

    return profile;
  } catch (e) {
    rethrow;
  }
}
```

and handle all cases of `Future` like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: futureMethodHere(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.hasData.toString()); 
        } else {
          return const Text('No data available');
        }
      },
    )
```

Comment: I got correct answer as you suggest, but In this I have to use manual id, instead of this I have a auto generated id. So, how can I use  it. 
I tried by myself but I got different length of id, e.g. in my firebase I have 20 length of id and when I got currentuser id by currentuser.uid then it return 28 length of id. Why there are length difference , and how can I solve it ?

Comment: It's because of their distinct purpose, auto generated document ID and UID of the user is of different length. but you can still use UID for document ID. Thus, when creating a new vendor account, store vendor's information using UID as document id for easier retrieval.